# How to generate and use a c++11 std::array with new to use the heap instead of the stack?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, std

I am aware that I am supposed to use std::vector if i want to generate a large array on the heap.

However in my lecture I have to use std::array instead. Since very large arrays are required for the task I wanted to force the compiler to create the array on the heap instead of the stack.

The only way I got my compiler accept this was:

```
std::array<double,10000000>* array = new array<double,10000000>;
```

However the program crashes once I try to use it since it seems to causing memory leaks. 
Is there anyway to work around this properly?

edit:

Here is part of the stuff I try to do:
I need to generate a large array, then generate random numbers and find the minimum. I think the rest of it should work with the same mechanics:

In Main:

```
std::array<double,10000000>* array = new array<double,10000000>;

genrate_array(*array);
std::cout<<"Minimum one loop:" << std::endl;
std::cout<<" " << std::endl;
time_measure<start_size, double>(plain_minimum, *array);
```

The first template function:

```
template<std::size_t N, typename T>
void genrate_array(std::array<T, N>& test_arr){
    //generate the array
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dist_int( 0.0,500.0);

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i< test_arr.size() ; i++)
    {
        test_arr[i] = dist_int(mt);
    }
}
```

The second Template function:

```
template<std::size_t N, typename T>
T plain_minimum(std::array<T,N>& arr, std::size_t start_index,std::size_t end_index)
{
    T min = arr[start_index];

    for(std::size_t i = start_index+1; i< end_index ; i++){
        if(min > arr[i])
        {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

This compiles but crashes almost immediatly.

Comment: You'll need to post the code you used to access it. (Hopefully not `array[3] = 1.0;`)

Comment: Leaking memory does not cause a crash. Please provide details on the crash. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then, update and improve *your question*.

Comment: @MartinNyolt your point is great, although technically, leaking memory can cause memory to run out, which can cause the program to crash on systems that use optimistic memory allocation.

Comment: A memory leak can hardly cause a crash. Why do you believe the program leaks memory?

Comment: Where does `time_measure` get the indices to pass to `start_index` and `end_index` parameters of `plain_minimum`? You don't seem to be passing any when invoking `time_measure`.

Comment: What do you mean by *crash*? Did you try to debug your program? If not, leaning how to use a debugger is invaluable to find and fix most errors by yourself.

Comment: @Angew `time_measure` uses `0` and `array.size` as parameters. This method is not doing anyhing but calling  `plain_minimum` at the moment since I wanted to get the array working fist.

Comment: Just post a [mcve], please. Something we could copy&paste to e.g. [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) and see the crash (or at least bad beheaviour) ourselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it seems to causing memory leaks

If you manually allocate memory with `new`, then you must deallocate it with `delete`. If you forget to delete the memory that you allocated, it will indeed always leak.

A better approach is to use a smart pointer that will take care of the deallocation:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::array<double,10000000>> pointer(new std::array<double,10000000>);
```

---

PS. It is good that you recognize that `std::vector` would be more appropriate for this. I urge you to ask your instructor to clarify what is the knowledge that you're supposed to learn from this exercise.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Well I do understand that I got to delete it manually. But the leaks seem to happen when I try to write the array. So I am probably passing it wrong to a template function which writes random double values to it. I tried to pass it like this: generat(*array)

Comment: @user1997675 you cannot leak memory by writing to an array of doubles. Why do you think that is causing memory to leak? The way you pass the array seems to be correct, assuming the function takes the array by reference. If you pass this big object by value, then you'll probably run out of stack space.

Comment: I try to pass it by reference but seem to fail. I edited my question with the code I used when I posted this question.  I am not quite sure where exactly I am doing stuff wrong. So is this put on the stack if I try passing it by reference or am I failing to pass the correct thing?

Comment: @user1997675 As I said, passing by reference is correct. The code that you show does it correctly. Very little stack space will be used. Why do you think that the problem is with how/what you pass to the function?